# Disable the text/html part in outgoing messages in OS X 10.8's Mail application

Tags: mail.app

I'm using the *Mail* application bundled with *OS X 10.8*. When switching from *Mac OS X 10.6*, I noticed that Mail now always includes a `text/html` part, alongside the `text/plain` part, in messages that include an image as attachment, even if the message's text has not been formatted in any way. Adding a different file type as attachment does not show that behavior.

The second problem is that the attached image is contained in the `text/html` part and not the `text/plain` part. Recipients whose mail clients (by configuration or by default) display the `text/plain` part do not see the attached image, which is very annoying.

Is there a way to make Mail never include a `text/html` part, by configuration or by using a specific method to insert the attachment?

Comment: text/plain cannot show an image so what do you expect the email to consist of?

Comment: @Mark Of course it can! You can use a content-type of `multipart/mixed` and set the content-disposition of the part with the image to `inline` (see RFC 1341 and RFC 2183). This will result in what is often called an "inline attachment". This works independent of the content-type parts containing the message's text. This is what was happening in earlier versions of the Mail application.

Comment: This discussion may be of interest:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3209246?start=0&tstart=0